# org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for notaProyectos in class com.elvolcan.saga.pojos.Proyecto

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

English is not my native language, but I hope it's understood. I am starting with hibernate, and in this JAVA WEB project that is with hibernate, JSP, springframewor I can not pass the login, where the following error occurs

**GlassFish**

```
Información:   HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Información:   HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Información:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Información:   HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Información:   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Grave:   Inicial SessionFactory creacion org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
Advertencia:   #{loginSdiBean.logear}: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
javax.faces.FacesException: #{loginSdiBean.logear}: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:43)
    at com.elvolcan.saga.hibernate.CatalogoSdi.buscarUsuarioPorUser(CatalogoSdi.java:982)
    at com.beans.LoginSdiBean.logear(LoginSdiBean.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at com.elvolcan.saga.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:33)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for notaProyectos in class com.elvolcan.saga.pojos.Proyecto
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:411)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:80)
    ... 65 more

Grave:   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:43)
    at com.hibernate.CatalogoSdi.buscarUsuarioPorUser(CatalogoSdi.java:982)
    at com.beans.LoginSdiBean.logear(LoginSdiBean.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at com.elvolcan.saga.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:33)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]

Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for notaProyectos in class com.elvolcan.saga.pojos.Proyecto
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:411)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:80)
    ... 65 more
```

I've been with this for a few days now and I'm not sure what it can be I think library use hibernate 4.3x along with glassfish 4.1.1 JSP 2.2 and springframewor 4.0.1
Does anyone know what it can be ??

thanks since now

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    //private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory1;
    /*private static final SessionFactory sessionfactory2=null;
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory3=null;
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory4=null;
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory5=null;*/

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            System.out.println("Construyendo Session Factory");
            sessionFactory1 = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
            /*Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder sb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            sb.applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
            StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry = sb.build();
            sessionFactory1 = cfg.buildSessionFactory(standardServiceRegistry);*/
            //sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Inicial SessionFactory creacion " + ex);
                    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory1() {
        return sessionFactory1;
    }

   /* public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory2() {
        return sessionfactory2;
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory3() {
        return sessionFactory3;
    }*/
}`
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://star.elrio.cl:3306/star?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">usuario</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">clave</property>
    <mapping resource="com/DatosOcOriginal.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/Usuario.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/EstadosOc.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/ProyectoCompras.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/Agendamiento.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/Solicitud.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/UsuarioAplicacion.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/Aplicacion.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/AplicacionVersion.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/Propiedad.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/Proyecto.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/DatosCorreo.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/ProyectoTi.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/EventoUsuario.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/Componente.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/Permiso.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/NotaProyecto.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/ArchivosCargados.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/DatosOc.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/Email.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/Evento.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Usuario**

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuModel;

/**
 * Usuario generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Usuario implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String rut;
    private String cargo;
    private String user;
    private String pass;
    private int activo;
    private String codErp;
    private String area;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido1;
    private String apellido2;
    private String email;
    private Date fechaCreacion;
    private Date ultimoAcceso;
    private int vendedor;
    private int admin;
    private int respondeReclamos;
    private double ventaNeta;
    private String ventaNetaString;
    private Set usuarioAplicacions = new HashSet(0);
    private Set solicitudsForUsuarioEmite = new HashSet(0);
    private Set solicitudsForUsuarioRecibe = new HashSet(0);
    private Set emailsForRemitente = new HashSet(0);
    private Set notaProyectos = new HashSet(0);
    private Set emailsForDestinatario = new HashSet(0);

    private Map<String, UsuarioAplicacion> aplicaciones;
    private boolean vendedorBoolean;
    private boolean adminBoolean;

    private MenuModel menuAplicaciones;

    public static final String APP_CONSULTA_TRANSITO = "TRANSI";
    public static final String APP_CONSULTA_HISTORIAL_CLIENTE = "HISTCL";

    public static final String MSJ_NO_SELECCIONADO = "Debe seleccionar un usuario";
    public static final String MSJ_GUARDADO = "Usuario guardado correctamente";
    public static final String MSJ_ACTUALIZADO = "Usuario actualizado correctamente";

    public static final int ACTIVO_SI = 1;
    public static final int ACTIVO_NO = 0;

    public static final int RESPONDE_RECLAMOS_URGENCIAS_SI = 1;
    public static final int RESPONDE_RECLAMOS_URGENCIAS_NO = 0;

    public Usuario() {

    }

    public Usuario(String user, String pass, int activo, String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, String email, Date fechaCreacion) {
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.activo = activo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido1 = apellido1;
        this.apellido2 = apellido2;
        this.email = email;
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
    }

    public Usuario(String user, String pass, int activo, String codErp, String area, String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, String email, Date fechaCreacion, Set tabUsuarioAplicacions) {
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.activo = activo;
        this.codErp = codErp;
        this.area = area;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido1 = apellido1;
        this.apellido2 = apellido2;
        this.email = email;
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
        this.usuarioAplicacions = tabUsuarioAplicacions;
    }

    public Map getAplicaciones() {
        aplicaciones = new HashMap<String, UsuarioAplicacion>();

        Iterator it = usuarioAplicacions.iterator();
        UsuarioAplicacion ap = null;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            ap = (UsuarioAplicacion) it.next();
            aplicaciones.put(ap.getId().getCodAplicacion(), ap);
        }
        return aplicaciones;
    }

//    /////////////////Permiso aplicacion //////////////////////
//    public boolean isTieneConsultaTransito(){
//        UsuarioAplicacion ap = (UsuarioAplicacion) getAplicaciones().get(APP_CONSULTA_TRANSITO);
//        if(ap == null){
//            return false;
//        }else{
//            return true;
//        }
//    }
//    
//    public boolean isTieneConsultaHistorialCliente(){
//        UsuarioAplicacion ap = (UsuarioAplicacion) getAplicaciones().get(APP_CONSULTA_HISTORIAL_CLIENTE);
//        if(ap == null){
//            return false;
//        }else{
//            return true;
//        }
//    }
    public String getVentaNetaString() {
        if (vendedor == 1) {
            Double amount = new Double(ventaNeta);
            NumberFormat numberFormatter;
            String amountOut;

            numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("es"));
            amountOut = numberFormatter.format(amount);

            return "$ " + amountOut;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 97 * hash + (this.user != null ? this.user.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Usuario other = (Usuario) obj;
        if ((this.user == null) ? (other.user != null) : !this.user.equals(other.user)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return user;
    }

    public boolean isVendedorBoolean() {
        if (vendedor == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setVendedorBoolean(boolean vendedorBoolean) {
        this.vendedorBoolean = vendedorBoolean;
        if (this.vendedorBoolean) {
            vendedor = 1;
        } else {
            vendedor = 0;
        }
    }

    public boolean isAdminBoolean() {
        if (admin == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setAdminBoolean(boolean adminBoolean) {
        this.adminBoolean = adminBoolean;
        if (this.adminBoolean) {
            admin = 1;
        } else {
            admin = 0;
        }
    }

    public int getAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(int admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    public MenuModel getMenuAplicaciones() {
        return menuAplicaciones;
    }

    public void setMenuAplicaciones(MenuModel menuAplicaciones) {
        this.menuAplicaciones = menuAplicaciones;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return this.pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public int getActivo() {
        return this.activo;
    }

    public void setActivo(int activo) {
        this.activo = activo;
    }

    public String getCodErp() {
        return this.codErp;
    }

    public void setCodErp(String codErp) {
        this.codErp = codErp;
    }

    public String getArea() {
        return this.area;
    }

    public void setArea(String area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido1() {
        return this.apellido1;
    }

    public void setApellido1(String apellido1) {
        this.apellido1 = apellido1;
    }

    public String getApellido2() {
        return this.apellido2;
    }

    public void setApellido2(String apellido2) {
        this.apellido2 = apellido2;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Date getFechaCreacion() {
        return this.fechaCreacion;
    }

    public void setFechaCreacion(Date fechaCreacion) {
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
    }

    public Set getUsuarioAplicacions() {
        return this.usuarioAplicacions;
    }

    public void setUsuarioAplicacions(Set usuarioAplicacions) {
        this.usuarioAplicacions = usuarioAplicacions;
    }

    public int getVendedor() {
        return vendedor;
    }

    public void setVendedor(int vendedor) {
        this.vendedor = vendedor;
    }

    public double getVentaNeta() {
        return ventaNeta;
    }

    public void setVentaNeta(double ventaNeta) {
        this.ventaNeta = ventaNeta;
    }

    public Date getUltimoAcceso() {
        return ultimoAcceso;
    }

    public void setUltimoAcceso(Date ultimoAcceso) {
        this.ultimoAcceso = ultimoAcceso;
    }

    public Set getSolicitudsForUsuarioEmite() {
        return solicitudsForUsuarioEmite;
    }

    public void setSolicitudsForUsuarioEmite(Set solicitudsForUsuarioEmite) {
        this.solicitudsForUsuarioEmite = solicitudsForUsuarioEmite;
    }

    public Set getSolicitudsForUsuarioRecibe() {
        return solicitudsForUsuarioRecibe;
    }

    public void setSolicitudsForUsuarioRecibe(Set solicitudsForUsuarioRecibe) {
        this.solicitudsForUsuarioRecibe = solicitudsForUsuarioRecibe;
    }

    public int getRespondeReclamos() {
        return respondeReclamos;
    }

    public void setRespondeReclamos(int respondeReclamos) {
        this.respondeReclamos = respondeReclamos;
    }

    public Set getEmailsForRemitente() {
        return emailsForRemitente;
    }

    public void setEmailsForRemitente(Set emailsForRemitente) {
        this.emailsForRemitente = emailsForRemitente;
    }

    public Set getEmailsForDestinatario() {
        return emailsForDestinatario;
    }

    public void setEmailsForDestinatario(Set emailsForDestinatario) {
        this.emailsForDestinatario = emailsForDestinatario;
    }

    public Set getNotaProyectos() {
        return notaProyectos;
    }

    public void setNotaProyectos(Set notaProyectos) {
        this.notaProyectos = notaProyectos;
    }

    /**
     * @return the rut
     */
    public String getRut() {
        return rut;
    }

    /**
     * @param rut the rut to set
     */
    public void setRut(String rut) {
        this.rut = rut;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cargo
     */
    public String getCargo() {
        return cargo;
    }

    /**
     * @param cargo the cargo to set
     */
    public void setCargo(String cargo) {
        this.cargo = cargo;
    }

}
```

**Where it stops working because of what is observed is the moment of creating the session**

```
     public Usuario buscarUsuarioPorUser(String username) {
            Session session = null;
            try {
 ** HERE FALLS  session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory1().openSession();**
                Usuario usuario = (Usuario) session.createCriteria(Usuario.class).
                        add(Restrictions.eq("this.user", username)).
                        uniqueResult();
                if (usuario == null) {
                    System.out.println("USUARIO NULL");
                } else {
                }
                return usuario;
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                    session.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Could not find a getter for notaProyectos in class com.elvolcan.saga.pojos.Proyecto
```

Looks like this is the root cause. From the looks of it Hiberate is trying to initialize the pojo "com.elvolcan.saga.pojos.Proyecto" and is unable to find getter method notaProyectos which it expects there .

you might want to take a look at com/Proyecto.hbm.xml and its corresponding Java class

Comment: Thanks, I did not see it ahi si funciona ahora